# Linux top Single/Separate-Cpu-States

Tags: bash, top

Is it possible to execute Linux `top` from console with *Single-Cpu-States* (without clicking <kbd>1</kbd> after `top` executes), even if someone set/saved `/root/.toprc` to run `top` with *Separate-Cpu-States*?

I was thinking

```
echo 1 | top
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `top -1` option.

But the variant of `top` installed may vary depending on distro.